# radiobuttons to the left of label using CSS

Tags: asp.net, css

I have been attempting to move the labels of my radiobuttons to the left with the help of CSS but nothing seems to work. Could i get a second pair of eyes to help me with this?

```
asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbid" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Table" TextAlign="left" >
                        <asp:ListItem Value="a">a</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="b">b</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="c">c</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="d">d</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

css:

```
    .FormArea input[type=radio]
{
  float:left;     
}

.FormArea input[type=radio] label 
{           
    float:right;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your radio button list you've set `TextAlign="Left"` but this get's overridden by

```
.FormArea input[type=radio] label 
{           
    float:right;
}
```

So no surprise that it's not working.

You have two options:

1. Remove both css style rules and simply use `TextAlign="Left"` in the radio button list or
2. Remove `TextAlign="Left"` from the radio button list and use the following CSS:

   ```
   .FormArea input[type=radio] { float: right; }
   .FormArea input[type=radio] label { float: left;}
   ```

Both approaches will display the text to the left of the radio button as required:

[image]

Please mark as correct if the answer helps you

Answer (score 0):

you need TextAlign = **TextAlign.Left** e.g. :

```
<script runat="server">  
     protected void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)  
     {  
         RadioButtonList1.TextAlign = TextAlign.Left;  
      }  
     protected void Button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)  
    {  
         RadioButtonList1.TextAlign = TextAlign.Right;  
     }  
  </script>
```

at the top of your page

look at this [link](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.ie/2009/03/how-to-use-textalign-text-align-left_20.html)

Comment: just correct your TextAlign="left" to TextAlign = TextAlign.Left in your current code

Comment: I did that in my code, however that did not seem to work. My last resort was to create another class in the CSS to override it all.